# Slow down in TCP/IP receive speed

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

I've written a simple .Net client that connects to a hardware device (FPGA) over TCP/IP. When I click a button in the client it sends a small (4 byte) "request" to the device, then immediately reads a block of data (approx 32kb) that the device responds with. The client code looks something like this:-

```
var stream = _tcpClient.GetStream();

stream.Write(requestData, 0, requestData.Length);

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    var tempBuffer = new byte[65535];
    do
    {
        var numBytesRead = stream.Read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
        ms.Write(tempRead, 0, numBytesRead);
    }
    while(ms.Length < ExpectedResponseSize);

    _hardwareResponse = ms.ToArray();
}
```

Using a Stopwatch in the above code typically reports 2-3ms to read the entire 32kb response back, and this timing remains consistent if I repeatedly click the button slowly (e.g. once per second).

If I start clicking the button more rapidly (e.g. every half a second) then after a few seconds the timings suddenly drop to around 12ms and stay there, even if I go back to clicking the button slowly. If I close then reopen the connection on the client and try again, it's back to 2-3ms times.

WireShark shows 3-4 ACKs coming out of the PC during the faster responses, but this increases to a dozen or more once the timing drops to 12ms. In both cases the number and size of packets coming from the FPGA is the same. I'm as confident as I can be that it's not a problem in the code on the client or FPGA (neither can get much simpler) - gut feeling is that it's a protocol or network thing. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the various answers in this similar question: https://serverfault.com/questions/215674/latency-in-tcp-ip-over-ethernet-networks/215963 ? I suspect that the issue is window size or ack algorithm reconfiguring itself pessimistically, but the only real way to get to the bottom is to try adjusting one thing at a time on the client and server until you spot the performance difference.  A lot of adaptive algorithms (like Nagle) are in use by default and can sometimes have unintended consequences on local traffic.